# it's convex sequence inequality

Tags: inequalities, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

A sequence $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$ of real numbers is called *concave* if $a_{0}=0$, and for each $0<i<n$, we have $a_i\geq\dfrac{a_{i-1}+a_{i+1}}{2}$.

Find the largest $c(n)$ such that for every concave sequence $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$ of non-negative real numbers, we have
$$c(n)\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_{i}\le \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\right)^2 .$$

I know $c(n)=\dfrac{n-1}{2}$ is well Khinchine inequality. But is it the best $c(n)$?

Comment: This inequality is not true: take $n=2, a_0=0, a_1=1, a_2=-1$.

Comment: By assumption $a_k\ge 0$ for all $k$, so your counterexample is not valid.

Comment: Where did you see $c(n)=\frac{n-1}2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

The constant $c(n)$ can be improved from $\frac{n-1}2$ to the optimal value
\begin{equation}
 c_*(n):=\frac{3n(n-1)}{2(2n-1)}
\end{equation}
for $n\ge2$.

Indeed, for $i\in[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$, let 
\begin{equation}
 g_i:=a_i-a_{i-1},\quad h_i:=\frac12\,(g_i-g_{i-1})=\frac12\,(a_i-2a_{i-1}+a_{i-2}),
\end{equation}
with $a_{-1}:=0=a_0$. Then for $j,k$ in $[n]$
\begin{equation}
 g_j=2\sum_{i=1}^jh_i,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 a_k=\sum_{j=1}^kg_j=2\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{i=1}^jh_i
 =2\sum_{i=1}^k h_i \sum_{j=i}^k 1=2\sum_{i=1}^k h_i (k-i+1), 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k=1}^n a_k=2\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^k h_i (k-i+1)
 =2\sum_{i=1}^n h_i\sum_{k=i}^n(k-i+1)=
 \sum_{i=1}^n h_i (n-i+2)(n-i+1)=:A_1. 
\end{equation}

Note that $h_1=a_1/2\ge0$ and $h_i\le0$ for $i=2,\dots,n$. So, 
the best constant $c_*(n)$ is the reciprocal of the maximum of $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2$ given the conditions that $A_1=1$, $h_1\ge0\ge h_i$ for $i=2,\dots,n$, and $0\le a_n/2=\sum_{i=1}^k h_i (k-i+1)$. These conditions on $(h_1,\dots,h_n)$ define a polytope $\Pi$ in $\R^n$. It is easy to see that for any extreme point $(h_1,\dots,h_n)$ of $\Pi$ at most two of the $h_i$'s can be nonzero. If $0=h_1[=a_1]$, then by the concavity of the $a_i$'s and condition $a_0=0$, we have $a_i\le0$ for all $i$, which contradicts the condition $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k=A_1=1$. So, $h_1>0$ and no more than one of $h_2,\dots,h_n$ is nonzero, so that for some $j\in\{2,\dots,n\}$, some real $c\ge0$, and all $i=2,\dots,n$
\begin{equation}
 h_i=-c_j1_{\{i=j\}}.  
\end{equation}
Solving now the equation $A_1=1$ for $c$, we get 
\begin{equation}
 c=c_j:=\frac{h_1 n(n+1)-2}{(n-j+2)(n-j+1)}. 
\end{equation}
With $c=c_j$, we have 
\begin{equation}
 a_n=\frac{2-h_1 n(j-1)}{n-j+2}. 
\end{equation}
So, the conditions $c\ge0$ and $a_n\ge0$ now become 
\begin{equation}
 \frac2{n(n+1)}\le h_1\le\frac2{n(j-1)}. 
\end{equation}

Given this condition on $h_1$ and the condition $2\le j\le n$, we can maximize in $j,h_1$ the expression of  $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2$, which is algebraic in $n,j,h_1$. The maximum is indeed $\frac{2(2n-1)}{3n(n-1)}=1/c_*(n)$, attained at $j=2$ and $h_1=2/n$. Details of this latter maximization can be seen in the [Mathematica notebook](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZfGtn7ZeuiE7qff5FYx6WFOHK0WeXFFvgsk) or its [pdf image](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZDGtn7Z4AATJNAndhH3cQTs5AXYPL6sADUV).

Comment: Nice,I can't open this book，can you tell this book name?Thanks

Comment: I don't think that I referred to a book in this answer. Rather, at the end of the answer I gave a link to a Mathematica **notebook**. To open it, you need to have the Mathematica application. If you don't have it, you can still see the pdf image of the notebook at the link at the very end of the answer. Also, did you see my question to you about where you saw $c(n)=\frac{n-1}2$?